# Unzip file in bash where extracted folder name does not match zip file name

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a shell script where I unzip a zip file and its contents will always be one folder.

In my code I was assuming that the name of the zip file will be reflective of the folder name (e.g. folder named **test** will always be zipped as **test.zip**). Hence I was extracting the folder-name from the zip file.

I hit a roadblock where a folder called **snaps** was zipped as **photos.zip**. Now, if I extract the folder name from the zip file, it will be the wrong folder name.

How I can get the correct folder name **snaps** after unzipping  **photos.zip**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it!

> unzip -l photos.zip | awk 'NR==4{print $4}' | sed 's//// '

Answer (score 0):

You're better off creating your own directory and using `unzip -j` so that all the files in the archive are extracted to that one directory.

Comment: I dont want to do that. I guess my option is to use  unzip -l so that the correct folder name can be accessed

Comment: @smokinguns: If you found a way to do it, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `dtrx` (Do The Right Extraction) for all my unzipping needs. The script detects the compression format and calls the right program with the right parameters. I strongly recommand it, and there is a flag to unzip to the a folder named as per the zip file.

`dtrx` is most likely in your package manager, and will save a lot of headaches.